# Phonegap build PushPlugin

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-build

I am using Phonegap 2.9.0 and trying to integrate PushPlugin. It works fine for iOS. But Android gives trouble! I tested it on an emulator and on 2 phones from my friends.

This is my `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id          = "com.phonegap.leuq"
    version     = "0.0.1" >

    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <name>LeuQ</name>

    <description>
        LeuQ app.
    </description>

    <author href="http://ovoweb.net" email="info@ovoweb.net">
        ovoWeb
    </author>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />

</widget>
```

Then we have the following `index.html`:

```
<!-- Load Phonegap -->
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>

    <!-- Load PhoneGap plugins -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>

    <!-- Load push notifications -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
            var pushNotification;

            function onDeviceReady() {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');

                                document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e)
                                {
                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');

                                      if( $("#home").length > 0)
                                        {
                                                // call this to get a new token each time. don't call it to reuse existing token.
                                                //pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
                                                e.preventDefault();
                                                navigator.app.exitApp();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                                navigator.app.backHistory();
                                        }
                                }, false);

                                try 
                                { 
                        pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
                        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering android</li>');
                            pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"196052025914","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});                // required!
                                        } else {
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering iOS</li>');
                            pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});        // required!
                        }
                }
                                catch(err) 
                                { 
                                        txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                                        txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                                        alert(txt); 
                                } 
            }

            // handle APNS notifications for iOS
            function onNotificationAPN(e) {
                if (e.alert) {
                     $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>push-notification: ' + e.alert + '</li>');
                     navigator.notification.alert(e.alert);
                }

                if (e.sound) {
                    var snd = new Media(e.sound);
                    snd.play();
                }

                if (e.badge) {
                    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, e.badge);
                }
            }

            // handle GCM notifications for Android
            function onNotificationGCM(e) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');

                switch( e.event )
                {
                    case 'registered':
                                        if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                                        {
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                                                // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                                                // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                                                console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
                                        }
                    break;

                    case 'message':
                            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                            // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
                            if (e.foreground)
                            {
                                                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');

                                                        // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
                                                        var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/"+e.soundname);
                                                        my_media.play();
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {        // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                                                        if (e.coldstart)
                                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                                                        else
                                                        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                                                }

                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
                    break;

                    case 'error':
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
                    break;

                    default:
                                                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
                    break;
                }
            }

            function tokenHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>token: '+ result +'</li>');
                // Your iOS push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
                // here is where you might want to send it the token for later use.
            }

            function successHandler (result) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:'+ result +'</li>');
            }

            function errorHandler (error) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:'+ error +'</li>');
            }


            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
            });
         </script>
                <div id="home">
                        <div id="app-status-div">
                                <ul id="app-status-ul">
                                        <li>Cordova PushNotification Plugin Demo</li>
                                </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

After building, I get the following screen on my Android emulator (and on the Android phones):

[image: Android]

It stops at registering device, but nothing happens afterwards (and should accourding to the script). What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your using [this plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/) then it requires a minimum of phonegap 3.0